# ERROR: typeerror when() missing 1 required positional argument 'value' in PySpark

Tags: pyspark, databricks

I got an above-mentioned error while running a dataframe in a databricks using Pyspark. I don't know how to solve this and where I have gone wrong. The code is as follows:

```
df_inner_select = df_promodata_daypart.select(df_promodata_daypart.sub_master_id,df_promodata_daypart.sub_campaign_id,df_promodata_daypart.resolved_network,df_promodata_daypart.hh_id,df_promodata_daypart.type,df_df_promodata_daypart.localpromoadviewstarttime_min).alias("viewerbytype").groupby(df_promodata_daypart.sub_master_id,df_promodata_daypart.sub_campaign_id,df_promodata_daypart.resolved_network,df_promodata_daypart.hh_id,df_promodata_daypart.localpromoadviewstarttime_min).agg(F.sum(F.when(df_promodata_daypart.type=="NonTargeted",1).otherwise(0).alias("NonTargeted_count")),F.sum(F.when(df_promodata_daypart.type=="Targeted").alias("Targeted_count")))
```

and also here I need to get the count of the type column as mentioned in the dataframe. Can anyone help me in solving this with quick response as possible ?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at the very end of your line:

```
F.when(df_promodata_daypart.type=="Targeted")
```

`when` function [requires](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.when) a condition **and** a value but you only passed a condition.

Comment: ```.agg(F.count(F.when((df_vw_promodata_network_type.NonTargeted_count != 0) & (prog_hh_id.time_shifted_live ==1),df_vw_promodata_network_type.hh_id).otherwise(None)).alias("live_NonTargeted_reach"))
``` in this y am i getting the similar error??

Comment: from a syntax point of view this looks correct. please set up a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48427185/how-to-make-good-reproducible-apache-spark-examples) and the error occurred